# Passing windows authentication between two websites

Tags: authentication, iis, web-applications, exact-synergy-enterprise

I'm working on a website that needs to be authenticated to via windows authentication in iis. To access this website you are required to login using windows authentication on another site.
I want  to pass that windows authentication to my website so they do not need to log in. is this possible? and how? Ive looked through impersonation and keroberos but they dont seem to by what I'm looking for. The site also needs to have the correct credentials because the windows user is a parameter to get sql information for each individual user.

Comment: Is the user accessing both sites from the browser or is one site making requests to the other server to server?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!, after a few hours of trial and error i found that it is paritally browsers issues and partially authentication issues. In firefox and chrome the authentications persist through, but not in IE. The solution was to change the authentication to windows authentication, then change the provider to Negotiate:kerberos in the authentication Configuration in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply!, after a few hours of trial and error i found that it is paritally browsers issues and partially authentication issues. In firefox and chrome the authentications persist through, but not in IE. The solution was to change the authentication to windows authentication, then change the provider to Negotiate:kerberos in the authentication Configuration in IIS.